# SUMO - How to generate routes without using shortest path algorithms?

Tags: random, shortest-path, traffic-simulation, sumo

When running a simulation in `SUMO` with routes generated by `duarouter` on a grid-like network, after a certain amount of time, the vehicles start to concentrate on the middle of the grid and in junctions due to the fact that the routes are generated using a shortest path algorithm (`dijkstra`, `astar`, `CH` or `CHWrapper`). How to generate random routes that are not created with a shortest path algorithm and do not make vehicles behave in that manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way of preventing this is to use [dynamic assignment](http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Demand/Dynamic_User_Assignment), that is using SUMO's duaIterate.py script to calculate route distributions based on the travel time in a previous iteration of the simulation. So if you have a trip file (maybe from randomTrips.py) just call

```
duaIterate.py -n net.xml -t trips.xml
```

If you really want random routes you can try to give intermediate points (option `-i`) to randomTrips.py but it will still give shortest paths between those. Alternatively you could write a simple script yourself which parses the network and the connections and tosses a coin at each junction where to drive next. In Python something like the following would do:

```
import random, sumolib
net = sumolib.net.readNet('myNet.net.xml')
route = [net.getEdge('startEdge')]
while len(route) < finalLength:
    route.append(random.choice(route[-1].getToNode().getOutgoing()))
```

This code ignores that the connections or edges are maybe not usable by the vehicle type you use but I hope you get the idea.
For details on using sumolib, see http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Tools/Sumolib

Comment: Before reading your answer I ended up creating random routes myself with the coin approach but without sumolib. Now I did the same with sumolib, thank you for your answer.